# How to stop getting macOS beta updates?

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

Previously I was using Catalina Beta

A few days back Catalina came out, and I upgraded to it.

Just now I've got the following update notification:

[image]

My guess is that I am still enrolled in the developer beta testing program, and so I continue to receive betas.

If this is correct, how to remove myself from the beta program?

And if not, what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Software update preferences, click on details under the gear icon and un-enroll there. This stops beta updates.

Emails and feedback assistant features are still there which need to be removed after signing into

- https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=4b98a8e6a3a3ce265b93c90207c442b53c45a1afa9ff1dc9bde8bb6928078d3b&path=%2F%2Fbetaprogram%2Flogin_to_unenroll&rv=2#

More details: https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll